# CDN Relative Path Appearing as Canonical URL (Rank Math SEO)

Tags: wordpress, sitemap, canonical-url, cdn

I have 1300+ pages that have 'non-canonical pages in sitemap' issue based on Ahrefs. All of the canonical URLs are DNS URL like this.

[image: Canonical URL screenshot]

I would like to set the canonical URL to be the same as the URL's page. Is there any method that I could try? Thank you.

P.S. I'm using RankMath for the SEO tool.

Answer (score 2):

In Rank Math, you can set the canonical URL on a page-by-page basis. In `/wp-admin/` go to either a Page or Post -> **Edit Page/Post** -> scroll down to RankMath SEO -> click the **Advanced** tab.

Add the canonical URL of your choice in the field like so:

[image: rank math seo setting the canonical url for a page or post]

RankMath, by default, tries to automagically set canonicals for post/pages. Hopefully, that overrides the annotation shown in your screenshot where you've got a CDN relative path. I'm guessing that for some reason RankMath is catching URIs from your CDN, and without seeing one specifically set, its automagical process is setting *those* as the canonical.

### Controlling RankMath Canonical URLs via Functions.php

If that doesn't work, or if you want to be able to modify the canonical dynamically, set a filter in your `functions.php` like so:

```php
// Allow changing of the canonical URL. 
//@param string $canonical The canonical URL.
 
add_filter( 'rank_math/frontend/canonical', function( $canonical ) {
    return $canonical;
});
```

For example, this would set to the current page URL:

```php
add_filter( 'rank_math/frontend/canonical', function( $canonical ) {
    return home_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );
});
```

If after attempting all of the above RankMath is still setting CDN relative paths as the canonical URL, the issue is likely specific to your site (which would be [off-topic](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for us to answer here). In such case, you'd want to take this up with your hosting provider and/or CDN customer service.

### Quick Side Note About Sitemaps

Also, just an FYI - Google assumes URLs submitted in a sitemap to be canonical. So best practice in general is to always leave non-canonical URLs *off* of your sitemaps. Unless something has changed, I'm fairly certain that's how it works. I'll look for someone to validate that in the comments.

Comment: Hi Mike!
Thanks so much for the brief explanation.
I have tried both the methods above, but it still displayed like this:
https://monosnap.com/file/0CgqPbdL7fy93bEShM8kVLVXKqEZc6

Did I add the filter incorrectly?
Or does the issue is related to the server or CDB afterall?
Thanks again.

Comment: No problem, happy to help. I dunno if you've added it correctly, I can't see your implementation!

Comment: I predict that this is a hosting/cdn customer service type of thing